# TextWrap in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl which a couple of buttons and some Textblock's. For some reason, the TextWrap is not working for this Textblock.

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 0 10">
        <TextBlock  FontWeight="DemiBold" Text="Account closure" x:Name="Message" 
               Margin="0 6 0 2"
               FontSize="18" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
            <TextBlock   Text="A random text here, here, here " 
                    Margin="0 6 0 0"
                    FontSize="18" />
            <TextBlock   Text="AZEQSD"
                         Margin="0 6 0 0"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="18" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

The output (The selected part = second StackPanel) while the part where I have the mouse = the second textblock with the TextWrapping property set to Wrap.

See here

[image]

Comment: Great first question! Its really nice to see someone ask the right way the first time.

Comment: A 'wrap', by definition, is breaking content down into a second line when the width of the content is more than the container. You haven't specified a container size, so there can't be an overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DockPanel adjust better with this kind os situation:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 0 10">
    <TextBlock  FontWeight="DemiBold" Text="Account closure" x:Name="Message" 
           Margin="0 6 0 2"
           FontSize="18" />
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Text="A random text here, here, here " 
                Margin="0 6 0 0"
                FontSize="18" />
        <TextBlock   Text="AZEQSD"
                     Margin="0 6 0 0"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="18" />
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit:

Quoting BradleyDotNET's comment:

> This works because `DockPanel` will constrain the last child to the
>   remaining space, and it fills its container which is the stack panel
>   that is constrained to the Grid.

Edit2:

You can have te whole second textblock wrap to the next line using a WrapPanel:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 0 10">
    <TextBlock  FontWeight="DemiBold" Text="Account closure" x:Name="Message" 
           Margin="0 6 0 2"
           FontSize="18" />
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Text="A random text here, here, here " 
                Margin="0 6 0 0"
                FontSize="18" />
        <TextBlock   Text="AZEQSD"
                     Margin="0 6 0 0"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="18" />
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Note that this works because `DockPanel` will constrain the last child to the remaining space, and it fills its container which is the stack panel that is constrained to the `Grid`. I would include this in your answer because to someone not *very* familiar with how each panel works, this is just magic. If the *first* `TextBlock` in the `DockPanel` was the one where it was supposed to wrap it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Thank you! However, It's not going to the first of the line which is what I want to achieve: https://i.imgur.com/EVlE77A.png

Comment: @Csharpnewbie what do you mean? You want the second line to start in the left corner, aligned with "A random"? Or do you want the whole TextBlock to go to the second line?

Comment: The "F" in the picture. Instead of going there, I want it to be aligned with "A random". So the "rest of the text block" should go to the new line.
Or (which I believe is harder to achieve) take the whole textblock to the new line If it doesn't fit in the first.

Comment: @Csharpnewbie the second should be achievable by using a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` on the nested Panel

Comment: @Csharpnewbie well, I don't think you can take the second line there, since the textblock is a square. Can't you use a single TextBlock instead of two? You can also change the StackPanel to a WrapPanel instead of to a DockPanel

Comment: The WrapPanel is what I was looking for afterall! thank you, both of you.

Answer (score 4):

`StackPanel` sizes to fit its contents unless it is actually given a size. So, in the "basic" case, word wrapping doesn't work as you show.

The `TextBlock` in the "main" `StackPanel` *will* have wrapping work because its width is constrained by using `Grid.Column`. The nested `StackPanel` has no such restriction. The easiest thing would be to put the second stack panel in the main grid (row 1, column 0) so it is also constrained; though there are a number of other possibilities.

Comment: I did that and It didn't do anything from what I can see. Should I set a maximum width for the grid?

Comment: @Csharpnewbie `Grid` expands to fill its container. You may need to add the updated code to your question to find your mistake.

Comment: @Csharpnewbie you have to move the extra contents (the "A random text, " and "AZQSD" text blocks)" into your new stack panel :). Also, make sure to set `Grid.Column=0`